# How to fix terminal android show space when inputed

Tags: android, git, github, terminal, gitbucket

As I said in the title, I am using the terminal in Android Studio to commit my project into Gitbucket. But when I run this command

```
git remote add origin https://XiaoKing94@bitbucket.org/XiaoKing94/tvob12_phanhoaivuong_dilibus.git
```

in the terminal, it just displays some characters then it displays space. Anyone know how I can fix this? I am using Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: Does the command work from a regular CMD session?